# How to reference Windows AppData file URI while in MSIX runtime

Tags: wpf, uri, webview2, msix

I'm utilizing a WebView2 control within a C# WPF .NET Framework application that is deployed via Microsoft AppCenter. This runs within the confines of the MSIX runtime which employs file redirection especially for the AppData (%APPDATA%) special folders. There is no problem writing or reading files written to the special folder using such pathing as:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyAppFolder")
```

When running in a non-MSIX runtime like when debugging in Visual Studio the path above goes to the classic LocalAppData folder:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\MyAppFolder`

When run in a MSIX runtime (after deployed from AppCenter) it will go to something like:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\MyApp_kp0rrpapc6x65\LocalCache\Local\MyAppFolder`

Now the tricky part is the WebView2 control is used to display a PDF file on screen. To do this you set its `Source` property with a URI. When running in a non-MSIX this works fine because there's no redirection. But with MSIX I'm having trouble constructing a good URI to a file within the special folder location. A URI that is constructed using the classic LocalAppData path of `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\MyAppFolder` seems to not be intercepted by the MSIX runtime and altered to its runtime location.

I'm following the guidance in this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes

I've tried constructing the URI as something such as this:

```
WebView.Source = new Uri(@"ms-appdata://MyApp/local/MyAppFolder/report.pdf");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` property to get the real non-virtualized path.

You could use the [DesktopBridge.Helpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DesktopBridge.Helpers/) NuGet package to detect whether you're in the context of an MSIX package at runtime and then decide which path to use:

```
string realPath = new DesktopBridge.Helpers().IsRunningAsUwp() ?
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path 
        : Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for more information about how to call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps.